# Strange keyboard response on azure cloud shell

Tags: keyboard

I am taking a Microsoft Python training using an azure sandbox. When typing open parenthesis the cursor turns open (as opposed to white filled) and does not accept further keyboard inputs. Clicking on the cursor resumes keyboard functionality. All other keys function as expected. Two ergonomic keyboards and two browsers give same result. I am running Windows MS365 on a Mac mini. I would appreciate any help. Thanks. Fred.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is planning to release a fix after 7/1/21:

[Azure Cloud Shell: Cannot Type left parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/447765/azure-cloud-shell-cannot-type-left-parentheses.html)

Comment: The issue appears to have been fixed.